# Проверка наличия формы на странице

Tags: javascript

Хочу написать функцию проверки наличия формы на странице. Форма любая. Если форма есть, то метод который ее вызывает ничего не возвращает. таким образом экономится память.

Если формы нет, то метод загружает ее.
Я вообще новичок и прошу помощи по коду.
я реализовал стек и решил хранить в памяти уже загруженные формы.
типа так.

```
let set = new Set();
function checkObkect(place, item, isContain){
    if (place + item in set) {
        isContain = true;
        } else {
            isContain = false;
            set.add(place + item);
        }
}
```

и мне как-то далее нужно взаимодействовать с параметром `isContain`.

Т.е. если в `Set`'е данная форма уже была загружена, метод не вызывает ее, если формы не было то она загружается.

Comment: Немного непонятно. Какой формы? Любой или какой-то определенной? И что необходимо в конечном итоге? Просто функция, возвращающая true, если форма на странице есть и false, если нет?

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос